# Pulling a Replicated CouchApp

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

My colleague did

```
couchapp push
```

to my local couchdb and I can now access the index.html via localhost

However, now I want to pull the couchapp down to my local file system so I can make edits and then re-push it back to both of our Couch instances. I understand how couchapp push works but can't find documentation on any function such as

```
couchapp pull
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command for this is `couchapp clone`:

```
couchapp help clone
```

Answer (score 1):

couchapp clone http://user:pass@localhost:5984/great-blog/_design/great-design-doc

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked with the [Python Couchapp](https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp) CLI tool in mind, but since that name is confusing and other people might arrive here just searching about CouchApps in general, I would like to recommend [Ddoc Lab](http://ddoc.me/) as a *design document/couchapp builder tool* that runs in the browser and can **pull** a replicated CouchApp easily:

[image]

By setting a new project, specifying the CouchDB database URL and design document ID, you can easily *Import*, then later *push to Couch*.